# in css grid, how to make entires in same row inline when copy and pasting the entries? (tried by setting display to inline but did not work)

Tags: html, css

```css
.grid-container {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-container>div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.item1 {}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

  <h1>Grid Lines</h1>

  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="item1">1</div>
    <div class="item2">2</div>
    <div class="item3">3</div>
    <div class="item4">4</div>
    <div class="item5">5</div>
    <div class="item6">6</div>
    <div class="item7">7</div>
    <div class="item8">8</div>
  </div>

  <p>You can refer to line numbers when placing grid items.</p>

</body>

</html>
```

I am playing with the css grid structure as seen in [this codepen](https://codepen.io/entropy283/pen/qBrmJeV) but when I highlight and copy over the contents of a single row (1, 2 and 3) and paste it somewhere both numbers are printed on different lines. Is there a way to make them both be in the same line when copy and pasted?

```
what I get: 
1
2
3

what I want: 
1 2 3
```

I have tried setting a display inline property to both the divs but that does not seem to help.

Comment: what have you tried, put that IN the question please

Comment: Please refer to the snippet from your external code - seems to give what you stated, please update your question and/or clarify

Comment: I just updated the title sorry about that but just to clarify I was looking to have all the entires be inline when I copy and paste the entries from the same row. for example when copy and pasting I get values (123)  all in different lines

Answer (score 0):

When you copy and paste data from a grid, the line breaks will (as far as I can tell) be determined by the original markup.

So if you want a group to be copy/pasted in a block, put them in a block element like a div. If you want them inline, use something like a span.

Since you want to mix the rows, you'll need to use spans inside divs.

Then sent the divs to `display: contents` so the span elements are treated as the grid elements and the divs are ignored for layout (until copy/pasting).

```css
.grid-container {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-container div {
  display: contents;
}

.grid-container span {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.item1 {}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div>
    <span class="item1">1</span>
    <span class="item2">2</span>
    <span class="item3">3</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="item4">4</span>
    <span class="item5">5</span>
    <span class="item6">6</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="item7">7</span>
    <span class="item8">8</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I just tried this in the attached codepen but this does not seem to work when copy and pasting still :(

Comment: Hmm. Looks like different browsers give different behaviour. Chrome puts everything on a new line. Firefox preserves the line breaks from the divs and spans.